# Date time and Date format localization with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, localization, django-rest-framework, pytz

I am creating API with DRF and Django 1.8 using python 2.7.x and Postgres 9.4. API is consumed by front end using AngularJS. I need to do time conversion to different time zones as per user set timezone. I tried creating a middleware as shown below -

```
import pytz

from django.utils import timezone

from django.conf import settings

class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.session["user_pref_timezone"] = "Europe/Paris"
        tzname = request.session.get('user_pref_timezone')
        settings.DATE_FORMAT = request.session.get('date')
        settings.TIME_FORMAT = request.session.get('time')
        if tzname:
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
```

And added it to settings.py under MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES as

```
'core.middleware.timezone.TimezoneMiddleware',
```

in settings.py I have added ,

```
USE_TZ = True
import pytz
TIMEZONES = ( (tz, tz) for tz in pytz.common_timezones )
```

still I can not see my time converted from UTC to specific country timezone. Am I missing something?